# How to connect R with Mongo and be able to filter on numberlong values and nested keys

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb, rmongo

I am trying to connect R with Mongo using 2 packages: rmongodb and RMongo.
I would like to create from R mongo query, which is based on index named id.

Id is a 19-number integer e.g 1234567891234567891, which is kept in mongo in numberlong format. Using rmongodb I don't know how to create query, which correctly understands my 19-number index e.g:

```
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "id", '6120367800331863610')
query <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
b <- mongo.find.one(mongo, ns=namespace, query)
```

or

```
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append.long(buf, "id", 6120367800331863610)
query <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
b <- mongo.find.one(mongo, ns=namespace, query)
```

In the first part of code, my query looks like `id : 2   6120367800331863610`
Id: 2 set data type for string not for numberLong and my query produces no results.

In the second part of my code, the number that I am giving is changed by r to :
`id : 18     6120367800331864064`. Id is now correct 18 represent NumberLong but number has changed. R has problem with treating such big numbers, I tried to change type for 6120367800331863610 using bit64 but type integer64 is not supported by `mongo.bson.buffer.append.long()`.

My second approach to that problem was to use RMongo package. Using that I was able to get id that I was looking for but I can't use there nested keys:

```
 dbGetQueryForKeys(mongo,namespace,"{'id':6120367800331863610}","{'id': 1, 'data.product': 1}")
```

Id  is correct but for data.product I get null values. When I change key to `{'id': 1, 'data': 1}` It gives me data.frame with ID and parse data to column, which is time consuming operation because of json-type structure of this part.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Regarding to rmongodb, it is definetely a bug/enhancement. Please, fill report at https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb/issues/
I hope  I will able to check this on weekend.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I post this issue on [https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb/issues/73]